# Register offsets from one source file in systemverilog source tree

Tags: design-patterns, fpga, system-verilog

I would like to create a source file structure so that the register offsets in my systemverilog design are derived from one file across the entire project.  The motivation is that all register offets are located in one file which can be passed on to the software team.  Subsequently any changes to the address map require changes to only one file.

At present, I use an include file called "address_map.h" which defines the address offsets.  The address offets for all the modules that have registers are added here.  This file is included at the top of the declarations section within each module.  The problem with this approach is that the same parameters get redefined across different modules.  I could work around this by enclosing the offset within macros that are specific to the module.  But it introduces statement order dependency which I do not like.  The e.g. address_map.h is shown below -

```
localparam 
  REG_ADDR_WIDTH                                = 8,
  REG_DATA_WIDTH                                = 32,
  NUM_OF_REG_REGIONS                            = 2;

//reg region 1
localparam
  MISC_REG_REGION                               = 0,
  MISC_NUM_OF_REG                               = 4,
  MISC_VER_DATE                                 = 0,
  MISC_VER_TIME                                 = 1,
  MISC_SCRATCH                                  = 2,
  MISC_TEMP_SENSE                               = 3;

//reg region 2
localparam
  ADC_REG_REGION                               = 1,
  ADC_NUM_OF_REG                               = 4,
  ADC_VER_DATE                                 = 0,
  ADC_VER_TIME                                 = 1,
  ADC_SYNC_STAT                                = 2,
  ADC_SYNC_EN                                  = 3,
  ADC_OFFSET                                   = 4;
```

Anybody know of a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to use SystemVerilog `package`. See [IEEE std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 26 for a full explanation. In general, packages are useful to store and encapsulate shared/common definitions; such as typdefs, static functions, and shared parameters. Working example of multi-package use here http://www.edaplayground.com/s/6/95

Better is subjective. It depends on what you (and your team) consider easier to manage. You also need to make sure your tools (simulator,synthesizer,linter,etc) have proper support. For example iverilog 0.10 within edaplayground.com does not yet support importing a package within a package.

```
package share_pkg;
typedef logic [ 7:0]  ADDR_t;
typedef logic [31:0]  DATA_t;
localparam NUM_OF_REG_REGIONS              = 2;
endpackage

//reg region 1
package region1_pkg;
parameter
  REG_REGION                               = 0,
  NUM_OF_REG                               = 4,
  VER_DATE                                 = 0,
  VER_TIME                                 = 1,
  SCRATCH                                  = 2,
  TEMP_SENSE                               = 3;
endpackage

//reg region 2
package region2_pkg;
localparam
  REG_REGION                               = 1,
  NUM_OF_REG                               = 4,
  VER_DATE                                 = 0,
  VER_TIME                                 = 2,
  SYNC_STAT                                = 2,
  SYNC_EN                                  = 3,
  OFFSET                                   = 4; 
endpackage
```